# CSS min-height not working for child div

Tags: html, css

I know it is very simple to add min-height property for a div.But the code what I wrote below is working if there are not c_left and c_right divisions mentioned.

I think you can get my problem if you see the below code.min-height not working for the container div.

My code is

```css
#wrapper {width:1024px;min-height: 400px;margin: 0px auto; background: #ccc;}
.header {height:150px;}
.container{height:1px;min-height: 100px;width: 100%;}
.container .c_left {float: left;width:50%;}
.container .c_right {float: right;width:50%;}
.footer {height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        header
    </div>  
    <div class="container">
        <div class="c_left">
            container
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </div>
        <div class="c_right">
            container
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Someone please help me why min-height is not working for container div.

Comment: You have fallen into a [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). No need to use `min-height`. The container won't contain the columns because they are floated and removed from normal flow. You could clear the float at the bottom of the container or give an `overflow` with a value other than `visible` to it. like `.container { overflow: hidden; }`.

Comment: Yes, this overflow works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies.

Answer given by Hashem Qolami helped me for this.

```
overflow:hidden;
```

for the container div made it extendable.

Answer (score 0):

I think is not working because you have both `height:1px;` and `min-height: 100px;` property, remove height or use a default value bigger then min-height value.

Comment: I have seen this keeping both height and min-height in one of the css sites.Even If I remove , no use.

Answer (score 0):

Child containers will not automatically inherit from min-height.
CSS2.1 specs:

The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

If you don't put a min-height on your containers, you're not explicitly specifying their height and they get an auto height.

For a workaround you could give your child divs:

```
display: table;
height: inherit;
```

Example: jsfiddle.net/xrebB/54/

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear: both` in class `.footer`:

```css
#wrapper {
    width:1024px;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #ccc;
}
.header {
    height:150px;
}
.container {
    height:1px;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.container .c_left {
    float: left;
    width:50%;
}
.container .c_right {
    float: right;
    width:50%;
}
.footer {
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;/*Add clear both*/
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="c_left">container
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </div>
        <div class="c_right">container
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is solution of your problem.
try this.

```css
    #wrapper {

      width: 1024px;

      min-height: 400px;

      margin: 0px auto;

      background: #ccc;

    }

    .header {

      height: 150px;

    }

    .container {

      height: 1px;

      min-height: 100px;

      width: 100%;

      overflow: auto;

    }

    .container .c_left {

      float: left;

      width: 50%;

    }

    .container .c_right {

      float: right;

      width: 50%;

    }

    .footer {

      height: 100px;

    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="c_left">
      container
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c_right">
      container
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```